# How to import pyinstaller modules/files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have files with functions which I've already compiled with pyinstaller. How would I import these files' functions into a new python file? Is this even possible?

(The idea is for them to be somewhat of an equivalent to a Windows dll. Ideally I would like to dynamically import functions from these files.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,no.The pyinstaller basicly creates a compiled .pyc file plus the interpter.

If you want to have something like the DLL, you may turn to the .pyd files.